# Why doesn't Jackson use serialize() Method of custom wrapper class extending LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, wrapper

I am using Jackson 2.3.2 library in a Spring MVC project and trying to specify a custom JSON serialization on a custom wrapper Object by implementing the JSONSerializableWithType interface which includes a method called serialize() that Jackson calls, when trying to serialize an Object instance to JSON.

Strangely this serialize method is called correctly as long as my Object wrapper does not extend LinkedHashMap<...>.
If my Object wrapper extends a Class that Jackson "knows" how to serialize in a default way, the serialize() method is not called anymore.

My wrapper class looks like this:

```
public class ResponseRoomOccupancy
    extends LinkedHashMap<...>
    implements org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializableWithType {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        // actual serialization of the object
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        serialize(jgen, provider);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/occupancy")
public @ResponseBody ResponseRoomOccupancy
getRoomOccupancy(RequestRoomOccupancy request) {

    return appointmentService.getEnrichedRoomOccupancy(request);
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why Jackson does not use the custom-defined serialize method on a class that extends LinkedHashMap?

**UPDATE**:

As Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out correctly, the JSONSerializableWithType interface is part of an older version of Jackson (<1.9).
However I dont know why this kind of custom serialization works with custom defined classes (e.g. if LinkedHashMap is exchanged with some class Foo<...>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Jackson 2 which [is completely incompatible with Jackson 1.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20) `JsonSerializableWithType` is an interface from Jackson 1. You can't have them work together. Jackson 2 simply doesn't look for `JsonSerializableWithType`.

Instead, annotate your `LinkedHashMap` type with

```
@JsonSerialize(using = YourSerializer.class)
```

and have `YourSerializer` do the work.

Regarding your comment and edit, Jackson has some default serializers/deserializers for **known types**, like `List`, `Set`, `String`, `Number`, **and** `Map`. However, it does not know your custom types. It must build a new serializer based on what it finds from analyzing your type.

Comment: Ok, that is correct. But I cant figure out, why it works with custom classes. I updated the question.

Comment: I think this behaviour of Jackson is not very consistently.